# Div element scrolling instead of wrapping

Tags: html, scroll, word-wrap

I have this html:

```
<div id="d0">
<div id="d1">Hello</div>
<div id="d2">some text here that could wrap but is not being wrapped</div>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
#d0 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#d0 > * {
    white-space: normal;
    display:inline-block;
}
#d1 {
    width:300px;
    background-color: #ff0;
}
#d2 {
    background-color: #aaf;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yH8sC/1/

If I resize the window (or result area) so that the whole thing does not fit on one line, I would expect `d2` to wrap. However, it is behaving as if `d1` did not exist - `d2` only wraps when there is not enough space to display `d2` **alone** on one line. I tested with Chromium and Firefox.

Why is this happening and how can I change the behavior?

Note: I'm using `nowrap` on `d0` because I don't want `d2` to be pushed below `d1`. But I would still like the contents to wrap when it can.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, try applying float:left to #d1. it converts it to an inline element. The element after it (#d2) will fill up any space left over by #d1. In this case, since it's a fluid element, the text will wrap. http://jsfiddle.net/K2XRe/

```
#d0 {}
#d1 {
    width:300px;
    background-color: #ff0;
    float: left;
}
#d2 {
    background-color: #aaf;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but the 2nd line goes below d1 when d2 wraps, I'd like it to stay in the same place horizontally.

Comment: Oh gotcha. I didn't understand that. So if that's the case, yes: table-cell is a good way to solve this problem. updated jsfiddle to reflect that: http://jsfiddle.net/K2XRe/2/

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to use `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block`
It's probably not as widely supported, but it should still work in the majority of browsers nowadays. The alternative would be to use actual tables :)